# Calculating flashovers on hv systems

Tags: voltage

How can I calculate if there will be a flash over between a 25kv catenary and a steel bridge above the railway electrical structure?

Comment: Need more information. Probably the air gap has a great deal to do with it. There are probably standards regulating distances for HV systems in your country, if not then look at international standards

Comment: Wikipedia says air breakdown is 3kV/mm, so you need 8.33 mm air gap during worst case scenario (structures flexing, cables moving when pushed around by train, inductive spikes in line voltage when train briefly looses contact under load) plus a generous safety factor... Is this a naive answer?

Comment: humidity, salt spray, particulates, frayed wires ---- all affect the trigger voltage.

Comment: Rain, rats, birds, Murphy, ....  !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the influence of rain, birds nests, kite strings and other contaminates to air that degrade the breakdown voltage ,BDV, of parallel line to line breakdown of approximately 1kV/mm ( and 3kV/mm for dry air plane to plane flat smooth rounded edges)

Each country will have electrification safety codes for safety clearances that maybe >=1m in order to withstand a possible induced 1 million volt impulses by either Lightning or Solar Flares with magnetosphere wobble induced magnetic fields called the Carrington Effect. (See Wiki)

In some cases these gaps may be insufficient to withstand worst case events.